# How to check if my website is being opened in a remote connection in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, remote-desktop

How to check if my website is being opened in a remote connection?

I am currently using

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession == true)
{
     terminal = "1";
}
else
{
     terminal = "0";
}
```

and it works fine in localhost, but when I publish my website I always get 0, even when I'm using remote desktop connection. Any suggestions?

Comment: You do not have access to this information. Why would you want it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have restricted access to my website based on IPs but it does not work if the user connects via remote desktop to a computer with the IP I allow.

Comment: Is this an intranet scenario?

Comment: When the user has the right do connect via RDP, it's ok, isn't it? Or are you trying to confuse security for obscurity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs *on the server*. So about which computer does it return information? About *the server*.

Comment: How can I get that information about *the client*? JavaScript/Jquery is fine for me. @OndrejTucny

Comment: @enb081 - You won't get it via javascript either. You *do not* have access to this information.

Answer (score 1):

In an *intranet* scenario, you could *maybe* block access from a host if it's running *any* remote sessions. However, this would also block an innocent user who is physically using that same machine at the same time.

In order to do this, you'd have to P/Invoke [`WTSEnumerateSessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), having [`WTSOpenServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)ed the clients machine (based on the remote address reported by the `Request`. Then, if there's any `pWinStationName` other than `console` and `services`, then there's a remote session running on that machine. But there's no way I can think of to correlate the session and the request - so all you could do (as I said at the outset) is to block *all* access from a machine if it's running *any* remote sessions.

Note that you'd need quite a lot of permissions to be able to run such code - you'd probably be best served by isolating it into a separate service running on your server under a privileged account, rather than granting access to the account your ASP.Net code is running under.